# split a string whilst use left join

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases. The first contains a list of upload doucuments and who they are for when uploaded and expiry date. This is stored as numbers representing each grade of person using implode. so column name 'foagrade' has 10,11,12 in row one. The second database is a list of grades and there ID's eg 10 = manager, 11 = HR etc. I am using left join and a basic html table to display a query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
"SELECT UPLOAD.id, UPLOAD.title, UPLOAD.faoGrade,UPLOAD.faoLocation, UPLOAD.date,   UPLOAD.expiry, GRADE.ID, GRADE.GRADE as GR, GRADE.id
FROM UPLOAD
LEFT JOIN GRADE ON
UPLOAD.faoGrade=GRADE.ID
where owner=$user");
echo "<table id='previous'>
<tr>
<th>Title/Document name:</th>
<th>For attention of Grade</th>
<th>For Location</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>Date expires</th>
<th>Delete this briefing</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id=$row['id'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['GR'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['foaLocation']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date("D, d M Y ",($row['date']));
  echo "<td>" . date("D, d M Y ",($row['expiry']));
  echo "<td><a href=pages/login/upload_delete.php?item=".$id.">delete</a></td> ";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

The query shows all the details but only shows the first grade stored in the column faograde (MANAGER) not 11 or 12. 
How would I explode or split this? So for each number in this column a grade name is shown. i will also have to do the same for column 'faoLocation', but working on one issue at a time.

Comment: Is normalization not an option?

Comment: No idea Strawberry never used it, i will investigate and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Also, you're selecting grade.id twice - and your result set will have *three* columns called `id`. This will confuse your application level code.

Comment: thanks didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

These tables should be [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), but with what you have already you can do something like this:

```
SELECT UPLOAD.id as uploadID,
UPLOAD.title,
UPLOAD.faoLocation,
UPLOAD.date,
UPLOAD.expiry,
GRADE.ID as gradeID1,
GRADE.GRADE as GR,
GRADE.id as gradeID2 FROM UPLOAD, GRADE
WHERE 
FIND_IN_SET(gradeID2,UPLOAD.faoGrade)
and UPLOAD.owner=$user;
```

**Update**
Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0468/6).

It is a bit confusing that there are multiple columns called `id` & `ID`. It's best to give them intuitive names like `grade_ID` or `user_ID`. From a normalization standpoint you could be using a relational table instead of the comma separated column (depending on how this data enters the database). Here's a [video about normalization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbjS7iujCbI).

Comment: This won't work - although FIND_IN_SET will, so -1. But +1 for recommending normalisation! ;-)

Comment: true confusing, Starting to understand normalization. as it has potential to have a lot of records so have already made a start. Thanks for teh pointer

Comment: @Strawberry Added a fiddle. You were right. Haven't had a need to use the FIND_IN_SET. Also I included the IN statement as well to show the results. It returns true but stops at the first comma.